# Couldn't make connection to MySQL after SQL_MODE is set

Tags: wamp, wampserver

```
I am using wampserver 2.5, I have to change some configuration of my.ini
I added these lines in my.ini file.

[mysqld]
SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

After adding these lines and restarting my wamp, I could not make connection with MySQL and the color of wamp icon is also orange.

Error:

```
MySQL said: Documentation

#2002 - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).
```